# Stop floating div with "fixed" size from floating out of container

Tags: css, css-float

I have a `<div>` container with a certain `max-width`,

```css
max-width: 300px;
margin: 4em auto;
border: 1px solid black;
```

that contains two things: 1) text, 2) a floating div with

```css
float: right;
width: 150px;
```

See my example at http://jsfiddle.net/uXEBR/.

When you reduce the window’s width, the floating `<div>`, as expected, extends outside the containing `<div>`, getting beyond its left border. However, I would like it to decrease in width so that it never leaves the outer `<div>`’s border. In other words, the width specification of the floating element should be conditional on sufficient width of the outer div. Is there a way to achieve this in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other option is a `media` query.  Here is an example based on the code you supplied.  Keep in mind that `.divright` element will only shrink as small as the longest word in the `div`.

[>>jsFiddle<<](http://jsfiddle.net/uXEBR/3/)

CSS:

```
.divout {
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 4em auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.divright {
    float: right;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin-right: 1.25em;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 225px) {
    .divright {
        margin-left: 1.25em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```css
width: 50%;
max-width: 150px;
```

Comment: Hi Eevee, thanks for your reply. While that does work in a way, it is not exactly what I need. The width of the inner `div` should typically not be relative, but exactly 150px unless the outer `div` is not sufficiently large. In that case I want it to narrow along with the containing `div`. Do you know if there's a way to do that?

Comment: change `50%` to `100%`  :)